# Active class added to li instead of img

Tags: jquery, uislider

I am using the slippry slider: http://slippry.com/

I would like the li tag to acquire the "active" class instead of the image within the li tag.

**Thumbnail code:**

```
<div class="thumb-box">
<ul class="thumbs">
<li><a href="#1" data-slide="1"><img src="/assets/img/image-1.jpg" alt="caption 1 <a href='#link'>Even with links!</a>"></a></li>
<li><a href="#2" data-slide="2"><img src="/assets/img/image-2.jpg" alt="caption 2"></a></li>    
<li><a href="#3" data-slide="3"><img src="/assets/img/image-3.jpg" alt="caption 3"></a></li>
<li><a href="#4" data-slide="4"><img src="/assets/img/image-4.jpg" alt="caption 4"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**Jquery Code**

```
var thumbs = jQuery('#thumbnails').slippry({
// general elements & wrapper
slippryWrapper: '<div class="slippry_box thumbnails" />',
// options

onSlideBefore: function (el, index_old, index_new) {
jQuery('.thumbs a img').removeClass('active');
jQuery('img', jQuery('.thumbs a')[index_new]).addClass('active');

}});
```

I have tried:

```
onSlideBefore: function (el, index_old, index_new) {
jQuery('.thumbs li').removeClass('active');
jQuery('li', jQuery('.thumbs')[index_new]).addClass('active');
```

But this adds the active class to all the li tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try :

```
jQuery('.thumbs li')[index_new].addClass('active');
```